# multiindex level output additional row

Tags: pandas

I am trying to set a multiindex to a simple pandas dataframe. The first index is type of shop and the second is the type of fruit. I was expecting to see two groups Shop1 and Shop2 for the first column but have ended up with three, Shop1, Shop2 and then Shop1 again. Why is this happening?

```
Area2 = pd.DataFrame({'01/01/2017': [2000, 2500, 100, 1600],
                '01/02/2017': [2000, 2500, 50, 1000],
                '01/03/2017': [2000, 500, 50, 1600,],
                '01/04/2017': [2500, 2000, 0, 1600],
                'Fruit': ['Apples', 'Banana', 'Pears', 'b/berry'],
                'Shop': ['Shop1', 'Shop2', 'Shop1', 'Shop1']})

S2 = Area2.set_index(['Shop', 'Fruit'])
```

Current output

```
                01/01/2017  01/02/2017  01/03/2017  01/04/2017
Shop    Fruit               
Shop1   Apples    2000       2000       2000         2500
Shop2   Banana    2500       2500       500          2000
Shop1   Pears     100        50         50           0
        b/berry   1600       1000       1600         1600
```

What I was expecting

```
               01/01/2017   01/02/2017  01/03/2017  01/04/2017
Shop    Fruit               
Shop1   Apples    2000       2000       2000         2500
        Pears     100        50         50           0
        b/berry   1600       1000       1600         1600
Shop2   Banana    2500       2500       500          2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
df = S2.sort_index()
print (df)
               01/01/2017  01/02/2017  01/03/2017  01/04/2017
Shop  Fruit                                                  
Shop1 Apples         2000        2000        2000        2500
      Pears           100          50          50           0
      b/berry        1600        1000        1600        1600
Shop2 Banana         2500        2500         500        2000
```

But first level of MultiIndex not showing same consecutive data by default.

Comment: So simple when you know how. Thanks.